# PHP Doc software on OSX?

Tags: php, user-interface, phpdoc

I use my OSX for dev. PHP and now i need to try PHPDoc but how? sombardy know a software? or how i can doe it?

i try to look here http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/ric_INSTALL.html but i hobe i can found a GUI software the out. :)

tanks for all help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a GUI, but you might as well get comfortable with the standard command-line PHPDocumentor.  It's not all that hard.  Just install it via PEAR, skim the docs, and try it out.